# Эффект нажатия на элемент RecyclerView

Tags: android

В этом приложении заметил, что если нажать на элемент и удерживать то элемент окрашивается в сероватый цвет давая понять пользователю что он нажал на него. Как в ListView. Как сделать также? А то я нажимаю/удерживаю на элементе, но непонятно как-то. В ListView тоже окрашивался в сероватый цвет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/imgRadio"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:civ_border_color="@android:color/white"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtRadioTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Название радио"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtRadioCity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Город"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnFavorite"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/favorites_button"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:onClick="onFavoriteClick"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star_black" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Зачем вы вопросы свои удаляете? Я потратил время на написание ответа, а отправить его не смог - вопрос удалён. Прекратите так делать. Мы тут не конкретным юзерам на вопросы отвечаем, а составляем общедоступную базу знаний. Ваши вопросы принадлежат сообществу, а не лично вам.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`LinearLayout` в котором у вас `view` элементы задайте `background:`

```
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
```

---

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cardView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"  >
```

Comment: Сделал так, но по нажатию на item списка не заметно что фон как-то меняется

Comment: Покажите код разметки, я только пишу приложение, тоже реализовал, у меня прекрасно работает.

Comment: В вопрос добавил

Comment: Сработало. Оказывается не в тот LinerLayout добавил атрибут

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас собственный адаптер для ListView, то повесте на него хендлер через setOnItemLongClickListener, внутри которого можно подкрашивать, анимировать или что-то еще делать со своими вьюхами.